# Detecting shake gesture by multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uievent

I need to detect shake gesture in iOS. I have done the usual stuff and it works perfectly fine. The thing is I have multiple view controllers in `UITabBarController` and I wish each of them to detect the shake gesture.

When shaking in any of the view controller , I get switched to a particular tab. The problem is if I shake in one view controller  and try to shake in other controller the gesture is not detected unless some action is performed in that controller.

I know I need to set `becomeFirstResponder` but I need to know how can this property be set to the current tab of the `UITabBarController` so that the shake gesture is recognised by all tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the code for detection (usually via a notification observer for shake) in a base view controller and and all the controller will subclass from this. Now you can write the code to move the particular tab in this base controller.

Problem solved.

Comment: I need to know which tab view controller was currently in view so I cannot make the shake gesture recognizer in a base controller.

Comment: get the selected index of the tab bar controller